# What does 'return' on its own at the end of a PHP function mean?

Tags: php, excel, function, return

I am working with a PHP library to generate Excel files which consists of several functions. This is one of the functions:

```
// Excel begin of file header
function xlsBOF() {
    pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0); 
    return;
}
```

I am not sure what the 'return' returns? Can someone clarify this please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its the same as

```
return null;
```

It leaves the function and sets `null` as return value. In some situation the statement `return;` makes clear, that this function returns "nothing" `null`, instead of "value" `null`. Other languages (and documentations) often use `void` for this.